# Anaconda - installed package to base virtual env but can't run in Spyder, pycharm or Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, anaconda

I've opened a new terminal and ran

```
conda activate base
pip install sailthru-client
```

Then I opened Spyder tried importing:

```
 from sailthru.sailthru_client import SailthruClient
```

but see:

```
  File "/Users/me/sailthru.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sailthru.sailthru_client import SailthruClient

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sailthru.sailthru_client'; 'sailthru' is not a package
```

In my terminal if I run echo $PATH I see:

> /opt/anaconda3/bin:/Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

and also in my terminal if I run:

```
python3

from sailthru.sailthru_client import SailthruClient
```

I see:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File "/Users/me/sailthru.py", line 3, in 
> from sailthru.sailthru_client import SailthruClient ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sailthru.sailthru_client';
> 'sailthru' is not a package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File "/Users/me/sailthru.py"` <- you have shadowed the module `sailthru` by creating a python script with the same name. Rename that and try again

Comment: I am both thrilled this worked, and sad at why my brain immediately thought there was a more complicated answer

Comment: Glad it works. Often enough the simple mistakes sometimes take the longest to fix, but are the least likely to be repeated